# Can I run virtual machines with CUDA GPU?

Tags: virtualbox, gpu, guest-os

Is it possible? I have nVidia CUDA GT555M 2GB and I'd like to have its power in guest OSs (mainly Windows, for games). I found few topics or questions about this, but they were kinda old, so I'm not sure whether it works now or not.

Ubuntu 14.04.4 - virtualbox-qt 4.3.36-dfsg-1+deb8u1ubuntu1.14.04.1